# Dirichlet series solution to Poisson Point Process question (repost from math.SE)

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, probability-distributions, dirichlet-series

Reposting here because the bounty on the [original math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741896/dirichlet-series-solution-to-poisson-point-process-question) expired, with no solutions or comments received.

For any discrete subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$, consider a digraph formed by placing an edge from each point in $S$ to a nearest neighbor.  The outdegree of each vertex is $1$; the indegree is at most the kissing number of dimension $d$.  Now consider the random graph process that arises when $S$ is sampled from a Homogeneous Poisson Point Process (HPPP).  I suspect it's hard to say much about this process for $d>1$.  But for $d=1$ the random digraph may be represented as a doubly infinite string of $0$'s and $1$'s representing left- and right-pointing edges, respectively.

I'm interested in $P(0|x)$, the conditional probability of $0$ given the succeeding string $x$.  For example, $P(0|x) = 1/(s+2)$ when $x=000...$ is a run of $s$ $0$'s.  In particular, let $a(s) = P(0|x)$ when the string $x=101010...$ has length $s$.  The first few values are: $$
a(s)=\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{16}{25}, \frac{61}{96}, \frac{272}{427},\frac{1385}{2176}
$$ for $s=0$ to $5$.  I computed these values up to $a(36)$ and noticed some intriguing patterns.  My question is how to prove what the numerics suggest.  The first problem is

(a) Prove that $\underset{s\rightarrow\infty}{\lim} a(s) =2/\pi$.

The convergence is fast.  The error $|2/\pi - a(s)|$ falls by a factor of $3$ for each $s$, and it is less than $10^{-18}$ for $s=36$.  After finding the correct coefficient for the leading error and subtracting it off, the remaining error falls by a factor of $5$ for each $s$.  Pulling this thread to its conclusion yields the following formula for $a(s)$: $$
a(s) = \frac{2}{\pi} \left(1 - \frac{4(-1)^s}{3^{s+3}} - \frac{4}{5^{s+3}} - \frac{8(-1)^s}{7^{s+3}} + \frac{4}{9^{s+3}} - \frac{12(-1)^s}{11^{s+3}} + \cdots\right).
$$
With more terms, the pattern in the coefficients becomes evident, leading to the following conjecture:

(b) Prove that $$
a(s) = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{js}c_{2j+1}}{(2j+1)^{s+3}}
$$
where $c_n$ is a multiplicative function which is zero for even $n$ and
$$ c_{p^{\alpha}} = -4\lfloor p/4\rceil\chi(p)^{\alpha+1}\;\text{ with}\;\;\chi(4k\pm 1)=\pm 1$$
for odd prime $p$ and $\alpha \ge 1$.  Here $\lfloor x\rceil$ denotes the nearest integer to $x$.

Alternatively, because $c_n$ is multiplicative, we may write an Euler formula for $a(s)$: $$
a(s) = \frac{2}{\pi} \prod_{\,p>2\\\text{prime}} g\left(s,\chi(p)p\right)\;\;\text{where}\;\; g(s,p) \doteq \frac{p^{s+3}-p}{p^{s+3}-1}.
$$

Comment: The conditional probability of a $0$ *where*? The labels $0$ and $1$ are attached to a random set of locations on the real line, and notions of a "typical point" are a bit delicate because of effects like the *inspection paradox*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory#Inspection_paradox . Anyway, I think you may effectively be asking about counting the number of alternating permutations of a given length?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation . (To observe the pattern 010101..., you need the sequence of inter-point distances to increase and decrease alternately.)

Comment: Thank you James Martin.  Yes, alternating permutations.  The numerators and denominators are both in OEIS, which leads to references to Hurwitz zeta functions for the connection to Dirichlet series.